# Parse Json String from HTTP response

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse JSON response from a HTTP request in Python. But I am getting the following exception:

```
 ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Python code:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.http.phishy-userpass-length', 255)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
browser.get("https://"+username+":"+password+"@"+url)
htmltext= str(browser.page_source)
html=soup(htmltext)
jsondata= str(html.find('pre')).strip('</pre>')
data=json.loads(jsondata)
print data['entries']
```

JSON Response:

```
{
   "count":1,
   "entries": 
   [
      {
         "id":15862,
         "application":loginAudit,
         "user":charan.kumar@speridian.com,
         "time":"2014-10-30T02:08:14.103-04:00",
         "values":
         {
                 "\/loginAudit\/login\/no-error\/user":"charan.kumar@speridian.com"
         }

      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I don't see you initializing jsondata.

Comment: Where does `jsondata` come from?

Comment: Note that the JSON you posted here is not valid; there are no quotes around the `application` and `user` values. You can test if something is valid JSON by using a linter. JSONLint.com provides one online.

Comment: sorry @MartijnPieters my bad i have assigned "html" to "jsondata". I have modified the code could you check now.

Comment: @charan: you are now passing in a BeautifulSoup object. Why use BeautifulSoup here *at all* since you are trying to parse JSON, not HTML?

Comment: As you have pointed my JSON seems to be wrong, thanks @MartijnPieters could you make that as answer so that i can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several problems here, but the two that stand out the most are:

1. You are using BeautifulSoup to parse the page. If you are really receiving just the JSON-like text you posted, BeautifulSoup is not going to be able to parse it. Even if it did not throw an error, the output is going to be some form of HTML, not JSON.
2. The page you show isn't actually valid JSON. The values for `application` and `user` are not quoted at all.

I'm also somewhat puzzled as to why you use Selenium to get the response. Unless there is JavaScript being executed on that specific page (for which you can indeed use a real browser to have it executed), that seems like you are using a bulldozer to try and crack a nut.

Using the standard library tools (`urllib2` or `urllib.request`, depending on your Python version) should suffice, perhaps with a few explicit HTTP headers being set. Personally, I'd use the [`requests` module](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) for tasks like these; it even comes with built-in JSON handling.

Comment: Actually i am not getting simple JSON string as response but a html string hence i have used BeautifulSoup to parse it and find the JSON stored inside a tag. I haven't posted all those details. sorry for not being clear

Comment: @charan: it could be that your method of extracting is incorrect. It could be that what you are parsing out is JavaScript, not strict JSON. It could be that the information you wanted to extract is better handled with a regular expression, etc. That's why you need to a) be clear as to what problem you are really solving (and not just problems with how you tried to solve it yourself) and b) give us a reproducible sample, so we can try and troubleshoot. You gave us neither, so all I can give you is general advice.

Comment: The reason for using Selenium is the URL which i am accessing is using a self-signed certificate, hence while using urllib2 libraries it is throwing SSL related exceptions. Thanks @Martijin i will remember your advice.

Comment: @charan: urllib2 doesn't really validate certs *at all*, so it should just work. There are several posts on Stack Overflow explaining how to force it to validate. Requests also doesn't verify unless you tell it to, see [SSL Cert verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification).